# rsync options to transfer big tgz files to zfs filesystem and snapshot later

Tags: rsync, zfs

I need transfer everyday a lot of compressed tar files from a hosting server to a zfs data storage server.

The standard way to rsync transfer seems to not zfs snapshot friendly. Each snapshot keep all daily data (not keep delta blocks only).

Someone knows how to transfer these files and be able to make snapshots keeping delta data ?

Comment: Have you tried using `scp`

Comment: scp file transfers all data, I want to transfer only the daily differences

Answer (score 0):

Your source is probably not ZFS?  Otherwise `zfs send|zfs receive` would be recommended.

You can tell `rsync` to perform inplace transfers, from `man rsync`:

> --inplace
>                 This option changes how rsync transfers a file when its data needs to be updated: instead of the default method of creating a
>   new copy of the file and moving it into place when it is complete,
>   rsync instead writes the
>                 updated data directly to the destination file.

Please read the manual further about the effects using `--inplace`.

Comment: yes is not a zfs filesystem. thanks for your help

Comment: @Rpereyra, did the `rsync --inplace` option solve your issue?